# If statement is not working in my program

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.7

```py
import time
name=input("Enter your name:")
currentTime = int(time.strftime('%H'))

if currentTime < 12 :
     print('Good morning,'+name)
elif currentTime > 12 :
     print('Good afternoon,'+name)
else :
     print('Good evening,'+name)

def main():
    import random
    guess: int = input('Enter a number the between 1 and 2 :')
    if guess <= "2":
        num: int = random.randint(1, 2)
        print("the number is ", num)
        if  num == guess:      #### this if statement is not working
            print('you won'
                  'your promote to level 2')
        else:
            print("You lost", ",Lets try again")
            repeat = input('Do you want to try again:')
            if repeat == "yes":
                main()
            else:
                print("Good bye")
                exit()
    else:
        print("the number you entered is grater than 5,Please enter a number between 1 and 2")
        main()

main()
```

The if statement in this code not working (I have highlighted that if statement in code) But else statement is working to both conditions.

Comment: Your `guess` is a string returned from the `input()`, but your `num` is an `int` returned from `randint()`. Did you mean: `guess = int(input('Enter a number the between 1 and 2 :'))`?

Comment: `input` returns a string and so `guess` is a string. Comparing a string with an integer (`if num == guess:`)  will never give `True` as a result. With `guess: int` you gave a type hint, but that's only a hint for programmers or tools. You'll have to convert the string to an integer yourself.

Comment: First of all you pass a string instead of int at "guess" variable. The same thing happens at "num". Also the "<=" that you use to compare strings, it compares the chars index on ascii table and not the values that strings have. One more thing try to use while instead of calling the same function when you repeat .

Comment: @dimosgeo `num` is created from a call to `random.randint`, so that one is an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `guess` is of type `str`, read the docs of [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a **string**
> (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that

When you do `guess: int` you are using a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). The docs say:

> The **Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type**
> **annotations**. They can be used by third party tools such as type
> checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.

In your `if` you are trying to compare a `int` to a `str`. Run this in the Python console to see:

```
print(1 == '1') # --> False
print(1 == 1) # --> True
```

So what you need to do is explicitly convert it to `int`:

```
guess = int(input('Enter a number the between 1 and 2 :'))
```

And change the first `if` to:

```
if guess <= 2:
    ...
```

(removing the quotes in `"2"`).

With these changes, your if statements will work.

Comment: btw There is no `casting` in python. Your example is of a conversion.